# address in listaddressgroupings and getnewaddress

Tags: wallet, address, private-key, public-key, regtest

I don't understand the differents between `listaddressgroupings` and `getnewaddress`

For example, I have a local blockchain ( regtest ) with 0 Block.
I create 101 block (`generate 101`)
I can see with `listaddressgroupings` this output

```
[
  [
    [
      "mvAH7VsxifvQdEZ46Rdt2oN3nB5BzaPqS8",
      50.00000000
    ]
  ]
]
```

What address is it?
If dump the priv key `dumpprivkey mvAH7VsxifvQdEZ46Rdt2oN3nB5BzaPqS8`

I have this result `MVA_PRIVATEKEY`

ok, If I search this privkey in `dumpwallet test.txt` that key in associate to this address

`MVA_PRIVATEKEY 2019-01-19T10:26:19Z change=1 # addr=2NAoHv7kDBhHND7YHcQKuDS8wCbEz87xLrv hdkeypath=m/0'/0'/0'`

Why is not `mvAH7VsxifvQdEZ46Rdt2oN3nB5BzaPqS8` ?

Now I want create a new address getnewaddress => 
`2NCGuG2v4RbaAKsZp1RQJ2ZpDM6WtW79Mu3`

Why this address begin with 2 and not with m or n ? its pk is different from `mvAH7VsxifvQdEZ46Rdt2oN3nB5BzaPqS8`

If I create another 101 block, I have a new address in `listaddressgroupings`

anytime I create a new block, I have a new address in `listaddressgroupings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand the difference between `listaddressgroupings` and `getnewaddress`

`listaddressgroupings` is very different from `getnewaddress`. `listaddressgroupings` just shows you addresses from your wallet that have been used. `getnewaddress` gives you a new address for you to receive Bitcoin at.

> What address is it?

That address is an address in your wallet. The reason you see it listed in `listaddressgroupings` is because you used `generate`. `generate` mines blocks and sends the block reward to a newly generated address. So after using `generate`, you will see a new address in your wallet which has the Bitcoin received from the block that was just mined.

`listaddressgroupings` is not giving you a new address every time you call it. If you just call it without mining any blocks and without using `getnewaddress`, then you will see the same addresses there. No new addresses will be created.

> Why this address begin with 2 and not with m or n ?

The address that `generate` uses is a P2PKH address which begins with `m` or `n`. However the wallet will give you, by default, addresses that are P2SH segwit addresses which will begin with `2`. This can be changed by setting the `-addresstype` option to change the address type that `getnewaddress` will give you. This discrepancy is largely due to legacy reasons; there's no reason that `generate` couldn't use P2SH segwit addresses (or whatever you have set `addresstype` to) but no one bothered to change it.

(Note that `generate` doesn't actually use P2PKH outputs. Rather it uses a P2PK output which does not have an address type. For convenience, this is displayed as a P2PKH address)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am little confusion. `listaddressgroupings` give the wallet after `generate`command. But these wallets are different from `dumpwallet`.
Where Can I see all address from generate? because with `dumpwallet` help I can read `Dumps all wallet keys in a human-readable format to a server-side file.`, but I can't find the address generate after mine block. These address have same Master priv key?

Comment: The private keys for addresses that are used by `generate` are in the `dumpwallet` output. They just aren't shown in the same form as `listaddressgroupings` because of the way that Bitcoin core stores addresses internally. The addresses from `generate` aren't actually addresses and are not stored as addresses. But their keys are stored, and that's what matters. When you use `dumpwallet`, the address form for those keys are not found, so it defaults to outputting it as the current default address type which is P2SH segwit.

Comment: thanks again for your reply. `The addresses from generate aren't actually addresses and are not stored as addresses.` Not address because miss some hash o check like base58check or what? for example If I create a transaction with `MVA_PRIVATEKEY`with which Public key check my signature? with `mvAH7VsxifvQdEZ46Rdt2oN3nB5BzaPqS8` or ` `2NCGuG2v4RbaAKsZp1RQJ2ZpDM6WtW79Mu3`

Thanks

Comment: `MVA_PRIVATEKEY` has only one public key. That public key corresponds to different addresses. When hashed with hash160 and base58 check encoded with version number 111, you get `mvAH7VsxifvQdEZ46Rdt2oN3nB5BzaPqS8`. When hashed with hash160, built into a segwit script, that script hashed with hash160, and then base58 check encoded with version number 196, you get `2NCGuG2v4RbaAKsZp1RQJ2ZpDM6WtW79Mu3`. It's the same public key in both, just different addresses representing different output scripts.

Comment: However, `generate` does not use either of those output scripts in the block it mined. It uses a P2PK script which has no address.